# Completeness of Opatch lsinventory

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, redhat

I'm performing an audit on oracle database changes on a Linux OS. The patch changes on the database is migrated on the OS level.

After using the command **opatch lsinventory**, we learned that this command has not been pulling the complete population of patches on the database. It is only showing the last patch applied. Contrary to what many online definition; which is ALL patches.

What could be causing this? What's a foolproof way to extract all changes (patch, scheme, table etc).

Thank you all!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The lsinventory would read from inventory_loc which is in oraInst.loc, so if you changed this value at some point then your patch information would be incorrect, but your patches will still be there.

If you are on 12c then you can do:

```
select * from dba_registry_sqlpatch;
```

Otherwise you are stuck with tracking your oraInventory...